# Keep first UL inside UL at the bottom of the div

Tags: jquery, html, css, html-lists

i try to build a menu and i need some help to make it work,
i have a ul menu with ul (sub menu) inside it, if i click in the first line it opens the second ul at the bottom but if i click the second line, it goes outside the first ul,

is it possible to open the second ul at the bottom of the first list?

thanks a lot!

here is the code:

http://jsfiddle.net/3ng6J/

Comment: I tried to put your code into JSFiddle to see a working example, but it doesn't do what you described. Have a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/Bg9L8/

Comment: i don't know why is not working, i'll try to fix it and i will update the question, if you save it as an html page it works fine

Comment: @Bazzz i update your code here: http://jsfiddle.net/3ng6J/ ,thanks a lot!

Comment: First, you would probably want that newly selected submenu is always above the old one.
Adding `.css({'z-index':-1})` to slideUp stack and `.css({'z-index':5})` to slideDown one does the trick.

However, from what you say, it is unclear whether you want the second line to be completely obscured upon clicking its link, or the menu wrapper extend to accomodate the submenu?

Comment: @unclenorton thanks a lot for your help, sorry if i'm not make it clear, i just need to find a css fix to open the second ul (submenu) at the bottom of the menu, something like relative position inside absolute position. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i fix it with just a `float:left;`  in the sub menu!

thanks!